# GA Basics – Best practices for page view tracking in dynamic PHP based sites

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

Sorry for the basic question, but I've been reading lots on this and haven't been able to piece together a solution (as a rookie developer) so thought maybe asking would be helpful to me and others in the same boat.

I'm attempting to install GA (gtag) on a PHP site. The initialisation code works fine, Google Tag Assistant is happy, but the site functions similar to a single page application whereby the content is all loaded in dynamically via js into a DIV (little floating overlays).

I've read that creating a separate analyticstracking.php file is a best practice for the inclusion of your tracking code on pages (using include_once), but doing this on the dynamically loaded php files seems to throw up an error within tag manager – "Same web property ID is tracked twice."

My assumption was that this was happening because the page name didn't change, which would be logical, but if true, how and where does one change the page name?

Is it best to do this as an event when the nav item loading content is clicked, or is it best to somehow include tracking data in the PHP files for loaded content (and how)? If the latter, is is possible to pass the page name to the included analyticstracking.php call on load?

Or perhaps I doing this all wrong and should I be using Google Tag Manager?

Thanks in advance,
Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution for your situation i guess will be something called "virtual pageview". Google Analytics documentation describes it here:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications

In shortcut:

1. Include Google Analytics (or GTag) code only once, for example in head.
2. Every additional content loading (which is key for you and want to treat as a new pageview) should send JS code with new "virtual" pageview to GA with datas seted by you (like new pageview title, new pageview url etc.).

Forget about sending events in this case as a "core". Of course you can also track events with nav clicks but first implement virtual pageviews.

Comment: Thanks a bunch - this was the ticket. I had tried this previously actually, but was overcomplicating it in my head and forgetting to implement it properly (by way of attempting to call gtag() without it being inside "<script type="text/javascript"></script?" tags. Thanks again for the help.